# what is operator | in sql and how it works

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to know, how the following condition works :

```
where x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 is not null
```

columns x1,x2,x3,x4  are nullable 
Is it same ?

```
where x1 is not null or  x2 is not null or   x3 is not null or x4 is not null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bitwise OR. You [find details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-or-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Try this:

```
DECLARE @int1 INT=0xFF00; --        => 65280
DECLARE @int2 INT=0x000F; --        =>    15
DECLARE @int3 INT=@int1 | @int2; -- => 65295 

SELECT @int1,@int2,@int3,
       CAST(@int3 AS BINARY(2));--  => 0xFF0F
```

You can see that the bit masks of `@int1` and `@int2` were combined to `0xFF0F`.

This can be used to check or set a special bit or a group of bits.